# SPEL not working in KafkaListener. Not able to resolve property

Tags: java, spring-kafka, spring-el

I have a code in which I am using SPEL in @KafkaListener.
I am trying to provide a global variable reference to the Topics field but getting the error

```
"Could not resolve placeholder 'topicKey.split(',')' in value "#{'${topicKey.split(',')}'}"
```

Code Below:

```
String topicKey =   "Topic1,Topic2";

@KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${topicKey.split(',')}'}")
```

Can someone help here what i am missing in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is quite clear

> "Could not resolve placeholder `'topicKey.split(',')'` in value `"#{'${topicKey.split(',')}'}"`

Your syntax is bad, assuming the property is `topicKey`, the proper syntax is

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${topicKey}'.split(',')}")
```

The property is resolved first.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{'foo,bar'.split(',')}")
```

then the SpEL splits the String.